# c++ hashmap ; update adding new keys and not updating

Tags: c++, hashmap

I have this code where I take a hashmap, take a key and update the value. However, the loop is never ending as the code is adding new keys to the hashmap rather than updation. Please let me know if you can help :-

```
typedef indri::utility::HashTable< Gram*, double, Gram::hash,Gram::string_comparator > HGramScore;

 HGramScore _gramScores;

HGramScore::iterator iter_score;

cout << "Sizeee " << _gramScores.size() << endl;

int count = 0;  

for (iter_score = _gramScores.begin(); iter_score != _gramScores.end() ; iter_score++)

{

  count++;

  cout << "Sizeee " << _gramScores.size() << endl;

   _gramScores.insert(*iter_score->first , *iter_score->second / total_score_count);

  cout << count << endl;

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're adding an item each time through the loop, so it can never possibly finish. What's your intention here?

Comment: Its rather hard to know what you're trying to do, but I suspect you should be simply setting `*iter_score->second /= total_score_count;`. No insert is required if this is supposed to simply update all score mapped-to values by division of the total count. Your description "take a key and update the value" suggests that is probably the correct course of action.

Comment: @WhozCraig that worked. But, I wonder why would inserting a value in hashmap with an existing key to update the value not work ?

Comment: For the very reason tadman mentioned.  Regardless, the real hint to me was the description stating "update". A hash table entry in a multimap scenario (which theirs apparently supports) is not updated with an `insert()` call. You update the hashed-to value by using the returned iterator and simply changing the hashed-to target directly, which should be referenced by the iterator's `second`.